# Converting SQL query from using join to correlated nested query?

Tags: sql, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, correlated-subquery

I am new to SQL and working on an assignment using Oracle SQL Developer. The assignment asks to solve the problems using correlated nested queries, but I am having a lot of trouble doing so. I have been able to solve the problems using join statements. I understand a correlated nested query to be where the subquery references the same relation used in the outer query. Is this correct line of thinking and how does this differ from using join operations? Also, in my use of SQL, I've noticed that to SELECT an attribute, it must be a column of the outer query (opposed to inner query). Does this mean all aggregate functions must be in the outer query if using correlated nested queries? Any advice would be appreciated.

For example, one problem asks to create a view with employee names, salary, department name, department manager name, department manager salary, and average department salary. My solution using joins:

```
CREATE VIEW DEPT_EMP_MGR_SALARIES
AS
    SELECT
        E.Fname AS EMP_FNAME,
        E.Minit AS EMP_MINIT,
        E.Lname AS EMP_LNAME,
        E.Salary AS EMP_SALARY,
        Dname,
        DMgr_Fname,
        DMgr_Minit,
        DMgr_Lname,
        DMgr_Salary,
        DEPT_AVG_SALARY
    FROM
        EMPLOYEE E
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            D.Dname,
            D.Dnumber,
            M.Fname AS DMgr_Fname,
            M.Minit AS DMgr_Minit,
            M.Lname AS DMgr_Lname,
            M.Salary AS DMgr_Salary
        FROM
            EMPLOYEE M,
            DEPARTMENT D
        WHERE
            D.Mgr_SSN = M.SSN
    ) ON E.Dno = Dnumber
    NATURAL JOIN (
        SELECT
            D1.Dname,
            AVG(E1.SALARY) AS DEPT_AVG_SALARY
        FROM
            EMPLOYEE E1,
            DEPARTMENT D1
        WHERE
            E1.Dno = D1.Dnumber
        GROUP BY
            D1.Dname
    );
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  It has been part of SQL for over 25 years.

Comment: instead of getting in a religious war over oracle vs ansi joins, how about answering the question?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith . . . Actually, I generally don't answer questions that use archaic syntax.  I find it cumbersome to have to rewrite complicated queries.